# High CPU usage with SDL + OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl, cpu-usage, sdl-opengl

I have a modern CPU (AMD FX 4170) and a modern GPU (NVidia GTX 660). Yet this simple program manages to fully use one of my CPU's cores. This means it uses one 4.2 GHz core to draw **nothing** at 60 FPS. What is wrong with this program?

```
#include <SDL/SDL.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO | SDL_INIT_AUDIO);
    SDL_SetVideoMode(800, 600, 0, SDL_OPENGL | SDL_RESIZABLE);

    while(true)
    {
        Uint32 now = SDL_GetTicks();
        SDL_GL_SwapBuffers();

        int delay = 1000 / 60 - (SDL_GetTicks() - now);
        if(delay > 0) SDL_Delay(delay);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that NVidia's drivers' implement waiting for vsync with a busy loop which causes SDL_GL_SwapBuffers() to use 100 % CPU. Turning off vsync from NVidia Control Panel removes this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Loops use as much computing power as they can. The main problem may be located  in:

```
int delay = 1000 / 60 - (SDL_GetTicks() - now);
```

your delay duration may be less than zero so that your operation may be just an infinite loop without waiting. You need to control the value of variable `delay`.

Moreover, in the this [link](http://forums.libsdl.org/viewtopic.php?t=4867&sid=46ae315baeddc18df645895405029e15): it is proposed that

`SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_SWAP_CONTROL,1);`  can be used to enable vsync so that it will not use all the CPU

Comment: But that is true only if the rest of the loop takes 1 / 60 of a second? It shouldn't take that long on a modern system.

Comment: @Scintillo, if that method takes more than 15 miliseconds, it causes this situation, could you check it with std::cout<<delay<<std::endl; ?

Comment: Indeed SDL_GL_SwapBuffers(); uses that time. Question is why it does that? It could be waiting for vsync but why it would use full CPU while doing it?